# How to sort li's in reverse

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm trying to sort an unordered list in reverse (vueJS 2.x), but I can't seem to find any documentation on filters like there used to be in vue 1.x (similar to the way Angular 1 did it)

e.g:

```
<li v-for="message in messages | orderBy 'name' -1">
```

but that doesn't work anymore.

I've tried using a computed property here:

```
computed: {
  reverse: function() {
    return this.messages.reverse();
  }
}
```

which *sort of*  works but the list items don't stay reversed once a new message is submitted via a form on the page.

The goal is to keep the list items reversed at all times.

I've tried attaching the reverse function to other lifecycle hooks as well such as beforeCreate and updated but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you need the items ordered in the code or on the UI only?

Comment: I suppose just the view would need to be reversed. The message data is being pulled from Firebase

Answer (score 4):

Indeed filters are gone in Vuejs 2... Instead, you use [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results) as you have tried:

```
<li v-for="message in sortedMessages">
```

and then:

```
computed: {
  sortedMessages: function() {
    return this.messages.slice().sort(function(message1, message2) {
        var name1 = message1.name.toLowerCase();
        var name2 = message2.name.toLowerCase();
        if(name1 < name2) return 1;
        if(name1 > name1) return -1;
        return 0;
    })
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That would end in an infinite loop since `.sort()` is destructive. You can get around it pretty easily though with `this.messages.slice().sort(...)` though.

Comment: Good point - thank you for pointing it out. I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to sort the list in the UI, then use CSS and you no longer need to sort it in the model.

for a vertical list:

```
ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

for a horizontal list:

```
ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Comment: This comes with a lot of side effects. A screen reader would still read it in DOM order. Also, you wouldn't be able to create a good test to see if things were actually reversed.

Answer (score 2):

In the migration portion of the vueJS 2.x docs, [there is a note on replacing the orderBy filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-orderBy-Filter),

As it mentions you should just be able to use something like [lodash's](https://lodash.com/) orderBy function like:

```
<li v-for="message in Orderedmessages">

computed: {
  Orderedmessages: function () {
    return _.orderBy(this.messages, ['name'], ['desc'])
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful here because `Array.reverse` is destructive and will cause an infinite loop. You'll run into the same situation when you try to use `Array.sort` as well. You can do this instead of what you have since you'd be working with a copy:

```
computed: {
  reverse: function() {
    return this.messages.slice().reverse()
  },
},
```